# Deploy static pages to domain root and rails application to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, routes, subdomain

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and deploying to Heroku.

I have static pages that are public to every web visitor and dynamic and "protected" pages that require the user to sign in in order to view them. Currently all pages are deployed to the website's root: `example.com/static-page` and `example.com/users/1/`

**My objective**:

- deploy static pages to the root, like `example.com/static-page`
- deploy rails' pages to a subdomain, like `app.example.com/users/1`

I assume the solution involves changing the routes file. Is there any tutorial or video explaining how to do so? I'm a newbie on Rails.

My routes file:

```
Dcid::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root 'static_pages#home'

  match '/home',    to: 'static_pages#home',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either have a controller serving your pages or simply put your HTML files in `public` an treat them as assets.

In either case if they are really static, you might want to cache heavily or put a CDN in front of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
  #config/routes.rb
  root 'static_pages#home'

  #Subdomain
  constraints subdomain: 'app' do
     resources :users
  end

  #Pages
  pages = %w(home about)
  for page in pages do
     get "/#{page}", to: "static_pages##{page}"
  end

  #Resources
  resources :users do
     get :new, as: :collection
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
     get :signin, action: :new, as: :collection
     delete :signout, to: :destroy, as: :collection
  end
```

This will create the routes you need. However, you won't be able to use a subdomain on Heroku, unless you use a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. Don't worry I bought a domain just for that purpose ;)